# How to make tailwindcss and scss work together?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make tailwindcss and scss work together, but I have some issues. I've tried 2 options

1 - `rails new app_name -c tailwind` - works fine, but I cannot use nested selectors, such as

```
p {
  h1.name {
     @apply text-9xl;
  }
}
```

2 - `rails new app_name -c postcss` - works almost fine, I can use nested selectors with my postcss config

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

but I cannot use @import statement wit taiwindcss code (basic CSS code works fine).

application.scss

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@import "external";
```

external.scss

```css
h1 {
  @apply text-9xl;
}

body {
  background: red;
}
```

In this example body is read, but text-9xl isn't applied to h1. How to fix it?

PS: I use ruby on rails 7.0.1 with cssbundling-rails gem

Answer (score 1):

It was discussed a week ago in this [issue](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/issues/133).
For now if both Tailwind and PostCSS are required,

> then you'll need the whole Node enchilada

as DHH stated in the discussion. Or, you can use this [hack](https://github.com/lnu-norge/lokaler.lnu.no/blob/c13668de1aaa723a1432b87db46a0b12d146c96b/lib/tasks/css_packer.rake) that is based on extra pre-compilation step of joining all css files into one.

Or, you can wait until this step gets into `tailwindcss-rails` gem.

It also worth noting that `@apply` is not recommend for general purposes in tailwind. As stated in the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles):

> Whatever you do, don’t use `@apply` just to make things look “cleaner”. Yes, HTML templates littered with Tailwind classes are kind of ugly. Making changes in a project that has tons of custom CSS is worse.
> If you start using `@apply` for everything, you are basically just
> writing CSS again and throwing away all of the workflow and
> maintainability advantages Tailwind gives you, for example:

Maybe, there is no actual need for all these tricks just for the sake of `@apply`.